# Nesting queries on JOINS and top1 with ties

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to use the result of the below SQL query-1 such that I can make another JOIN on this with my second query result to retrieve Fundsrc on the common ID - Project.

QUERY 1-

```
SELECT top 1 with ties
t.project, r.rel_value AS "FundSrc" ,r.date_to

from atsproject t 

LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue r ON(t.client=r.client AND r.rel_attr_id='ZB18' AND r.attribute_id='B0' AND t.project=r.att_value) 

WHERE  r.date_To > '04/30/2020' and status='n'

ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by t.project order by t.project, r.rel_value)
```

I cannot put the JOIN inside the above query as it will mess with the result. Instead, if I can do a nesting on this then I think that should solve the issue.

My second query is -

```
SELECT 
t.project,t.work_order as activity,  r1.labor_funding_source2_fx AS "Designated Labour Funding"
FROM atsworkorder t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN afxactlaborfund r1 ON( t.work_order = r1.dim_value AND t.client = r1.client AND r1.attribute_id = 'BF') 
WHERE t.client='PC' and t.status = 'N'
```

The Output should be -
t.project,t.work_order from query 2 + Fundsrc from Query 1, with the common id on Project ID.

Any suggestions on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your question accordingly so it’s easier to read.

Comment: I am sorry. I am very new to stack overflow. Is the format of my question unreadable? I cant see exactly where the issue is with the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap 'subqueries' in parenthesis and then join them.

Can you try this?:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT top 1 with ties t.project,
      r.rel_value AS "FundSrc",
      r.date_to
   FROM atsproject t
   LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue r
      ON t.client=r.client
      AND r.rel_attr_id='ZB18'
      AND r.attribute_id='B0'
      AND t.project=r.att_value
   WHERE r.date_To > '04/30/2020' and status='n'
   ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by t.project order by t.project, r.rel_value)
   ) AS TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN 
   (
   SELECT t.project,
         t.work_order as activity,
         r1.labor_funding_source2_fx AS "Designated Labour Funding"
   FROM atsworkorder t
   LEFT OUTER JOIN afxactlaborfund r1
      ON t.work_order = r1.dim_value
      AND t.client = r1.client
      AND r1.attribute_id = 'BF'
   WHERE t.client='PC' and t.status = 'N' 
   ) AS TABLE_2
   ON TABLE_1.PROJECT = TABLE2.PROJECT
```

I am pretty sure an `ORDER BY` clause will not work within a subquery. Thus, this should probably work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT t.project,
      r.rel_value AS "FundSrc",
      r.date_to,
      row_number() over (partition by t.project order by t.project, r.rel_value) AS MY_RANKING
   FROM atsproject t
   LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue r
      ON t.client=r.client
      AND r.rel_attr_id='ZB18'
      AND r.attribute_id='B0'
      AND t.project=r.att_value
   WHERE r.date_To > '04/30/2020' and status='n'
   ) AS TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN 
   (
   SELECT t.project,
         t.work_order as activity,
         r1.labor_funding_source2_fx AS "Designated Labour Funding"
   FROM atsworkorder t
   LEFT OUTER JOIN afxactlaborfund r1
      ON t.work_order = r1.dim_value
      AND t.client = r1.client
      AND r1.attribute_id = 'BF'
   WHERE t.client='PC' and t.status = 'N' 
   ) AS TABLE_2
   ON TABLE_1.PROJECT = TABLE2.PROJECT

WHERE TABLE_1.MY_RANKING = 1
```

Note: On your formatting, wrap words within ` when they refer to code. They will look like `this`.
Wrap blocks of code within three of those (three at the beginning and at the end). It will look like the blocks of code above.

Comment: Thank you Andres, I am going to try this today and will ;let you know.